# HorizontalContentAlignment in DataGridHeader

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mahapps.metro

In my DataGrid Headers I would like to align the content to the right. Currently I'm doing this using a style on the DataGrid:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" x:Key="ResultatenHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
</Style>
```

However this produces the following result:

[image: result]

As you can see my header has two lines, I've done this with the following code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="neerslag&#x0a;(m³)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
```

How would I go about making the second line (the unit, m3) also align right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than setting the ContentTemplate to Null like dkozl suggested I decided to edit the ContentTemplate to:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock TextBlock.FontWeight="SemiBold"
                        Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                        TextAlignment="Right"/>
          </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I applied this to all my tables involving numbers and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextBlock` as `Header` content and then you can right align text

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="neerslag&#x0a;(m³)" TextAlignment="Right"/>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

**EDIT**

Because you use MahApps Metro which changes template for `DataGridColumnHeader` and as part of that it changes `ContentTemplate` to be `TextBlock` ([Controls.DataGrid.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.DataGrid.xaml) line 238) so you cannot put anything into `Header` any more as it will be converted to string. You can change style for `DataGridColumnHeader`, base it on Metro style and change `ContentTemplate` to be null which will allow you again to put anything you want, like `TextBlock`, in the `Header` yet it should keep Metro style

```xml
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/controls.datagrid.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>           
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
           <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
           <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
       </Style>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Trying this my header says: System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock

Comment: Do you change template for `DataGridColumnHeader`? if yes do you use `TextBlock` or `ContentPresenter` to display `Header` content?

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Width="100">
                                                                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="neerslag&#x0a;(m³)" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                                                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                                                </DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: Do you change template? I can see from your image that it's not standard looks for column header.

Comment: It's because it changes `ContentTemplate` of `DataGridColumnHeader` to `TextBlock` ([Controls.DataGrid.xaml](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.DataGrid.xaml) line 238) to make the text bold and upper case which strips you of possibility putting anything you want in column header. With MahApps you can use only strings but then you have problem when you want to do what you're after

Comment: I geuss I'll just use whitespaces then to solve it :(

Comment: Hey, I just readdressed this issue and with the help of your answer I managed to come up with a solution, check my answer :)